# How did Obi-Wan know Darth Vader was Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, obi-wan-kenobi

As noted in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55/when-did-obi-wan-kenobi-learn-that-anakin-was-dead) (similar, but not duplicate), Obi-Wan *did know* that Anakin was not dead, and that he was, in fact, Darth Vader. In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/what-did-the-general-public-know-about-darth-vader), it is clear that the fact that Anakin was Darth Vader was *not* common knowledge at all.

So when how did Obi-Wan know Anakin had become Darth Vader? I don't recall reading any EU novels with any interaction between them.

Did he know at the time of their duel on Mustafar that Anakin was called 'Darth Vader'? If so, then he simply would have heard about Vader in other events and this is a dumb question

Comment: He used the Force, Luke.

Comment: @4ichard - that does not answer thw question. None of the answers say *how* he knew - they all met mention *that* he knew.

Comment: @ssumner - Gnovice' answer seems to answer this question. He left him for dead, then felt with the Force that he might not be, then got confirmation when the remaining Jedi rallied against Vader.

Comment: @Richard - no, it absolutely does not. I am well aware (and linked to that question) that Obi-wan knew Vader was Anakin after Mustafar - my question was *how* he found out at/before Mustafar. Gnovices' answer does not refer to events pre-Mustafar

Comment: @SSumner I feel that to distinguish it from the other answered question, we have to include the 'when' aspect - it is clear that Obi-Wan knew, and that he could tell through the force, but what isn't clear is when in the history of the films he actually found out, and that is incredibly relevant to HOW he found out (which, as it turns out from Phantom's answer, had nothing to do with the force at all).

Comment: @Zibbobz We really don't. Everything in the other question is about Anakin/Vader's fate, not identity.

Comment: @Zibboz - phantom said it. The time really is irrelevant. I only brought it up as another point in support of why it shoul not have been closedd

Comment: I've marked this to reopen since it looks like the site glitched by allowing me to close it on my own. For the record, I still think this is a dupe.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Obi-Wan saw [a security hologram of Palpatine/Sidious referring to him as "Lord Vader"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=55&v=Ib2v8atzt5c&feature=youtu.be)

From the script:

> *185 INT. CORUSCANT-JEDI TEMPLE-CONTROL CENTER-NIGHT*
>
> *OBI-WAN enters the Main Control Center with YODA and heads for the hologram area.*
>
> **OBI-WAN:** Wait, Master. There is something I must know . . .
>
> **YODA:** If into the security recordings you go, only pain will you find.
>
> **OBI-WAN:** I must know the truth, Master.
>
> *OBI-WAN moves to a panel and flips some switches. He sees a HOLOGRAM of ANAKIN slaughtering JEDI, including the YOUNG ONES. OBI-WAN and YODA react.*
>
> **OBI-WAN:** *(continuing)* It can't be . . . It can't be . . .
>
> *As ANAKIN surveys the carnage, a DARK-ROBED SITH LORD enters. ANAKIN turns to DARTH SIDIOUS and kneels before him.*
>
> **ANAKIN:** The traitors have been taken care of, Lord Sidious.
>
> **DARTH SIDIOUS:** Good . . . good . . . You have done well, my new apprentice. Do you feel your power growing?
>
> **ANAKIN:** Yes, My Master.
>
> **DARTH SIDIOUS: Now, Lord Vader, now go and bring peace to the Empire.**
>
> *OBI-WAN watches in horror. Tears well up in his eyes.*

Comment: What script is this from? I'm assuming The Clone Wars, as I don't recognize it, but it could also simply be a scene from the horrid prequels that I've simply forgotten...

Comment: @Kromey Revenge of the Sith