# Does R2D2 know that Darth Vader is Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, r2-d2

I have looked through a lot of posts on here, but cannot find any specific answer for this question.

Now, it's been pretty fairly established that due to having his memory wiped, C-3PO would not recognize Anakin/Darth Vader. However, it seems that R2D2 either never had his memory wiped - which explains his quirky behavior - or only had certain parts reprogrammed.

**Does R2-D2 know that Anakin is Vader, either from scanning him or simply because he's been told?** It seems that if anyone aside from Obi Wan would know him, it would be him.

Comment: Kenobi and Yoda both know that Vader is Anakin; (["How did Obi-Wan know Darth Vader was Anakin?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35576/how-did-obi-wan-know-darth-vader-was-anakin)") and R2-D2 was with both of them before setting off for Alderaan

Comment: Does R2-D2 really **know** _anything_? He's a droid, after all… he can store, retrieve, and analyse information, but can he **know**?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - If you read the novels, he's actually quite a clever chap and certainly the brains of the operation as far as him and C-3PO are concerned

Comment: @Richard No doubt about that (that's clear from the movies too); but is that actual knowledge? I'm being pseudo-philosophical here, but I'd say true knowledge requires a higher level of abstract reflection than AI is capable of, even in _Star Wars_ (unless of course the novelisations make it clear that droids are actually capable of actual reflection and all that entails).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - In the novels, he's (occasionally) quite eloquent and both droids are capable of abstract thought and quiet philosophy. C-3PO is permanently baffled by human behaviour though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet R2D2 knows everything.

Comment: @Richard The accepted answer at the question this was marked as a duplicate of uses bad sourcing and is terrible. This one should not be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @user45623 If you think the answer to the other question is bad, feel free to provide a better one. The quality of the answer on the first question doesn't change the fact that this one is asking the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, I did not see the other duplicates before I posted this.