# Does Padme know the name "Darth Vader"?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, revenge-of-the-sith, anakin-skywalker, padme

From the script:

> Anakin Skywalker: Love won't save you, Padme. Only my new powers can do that!
>
> Padmé: But at what cost? You're a good person, don't do this!
>
> Anakin Skywalker: I won't lose you the way I lost my mother. I am becoming more  powerful than any Jedi has ever dreamed of, and I'm doing it for you. To protect you.
>
> Padmé: Come away with me. Help me raise our child far away. Leave everything else behind while we still can!
>
> Anakin Skywalker: No. Don't you see? We don't have to run away anymore! We no longer have to hide our love for each other. I am more powerful than the Chancellor, I... I can overthrow him! And together, you and I can rule the galaxy! We can make things the way we want them to be!
>
> Padmé: I don't believe what I'm hearing! Obi-Wan was right... you've changed! You have turned to the dark side! You're not Anakin anymore!

Does Padme know the name Darth Vader? In "Revenge of the Sith," Padme
knows that Anakin has fallen to the Dark Side (she must know from his
choking her). But does she know that Anakin is Darth Vader? I.e. was
she aware of the *name* "Darth Vader"?

Comment: [SPOILER ALERT]He was named darth vader already after palaptine bestowed him after the death of mace windu

Comment: You are much more likely to get a response if you put some effort into writing your questions (e.g. use proper capitalization). Why should I put any effort into answering your question if you obviously didn't put any effort into *asking* it?

Comment: I doubt she knew of the name, she probably died too quickly and semi-inexplicably.

Answer (score 5):

According to the movie - No.

The only person aware of that name is Palpatine. Later, when he flies to Mustafar to save Darth Vader, he uses this name as a reference to his ship captain. The common belief was that Anakin Skywalker was terminated with Order 66 along with his fellow Jedi, and neither Palpatine, not Vader did object. The only people who knew were Yoda and Obi-Wan.

Comment: "The only person aware of that name is Palpatine." Not quite. Even at that time, [Yoda, and Obi-Wan both know Anakin is now Vader](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/35577/5184), and Palpatine mentions Vader to Mas Amedda.

Comment: I agree. Anyway, neither of them had a chance to tell her before she was force-choked by Vader and brought into the semi-conscious state from which she never recovered.

Answer (score 3):

There is no conclusive answer, but Obi-Wan did tell Padme about the "terrible things" and that Vader had turned to the Dark Side and killed younglings. How did Obi-Wan know that? Well, he watched holo-recordings from the Temple, including Anakin kneeling before Palpatine and Palpatine calling him Lord Vader. Did Obi-Wan mention Anakin's new name to Padme? This is unknown, but possible.